# Alterar Background da página conforme o usuário escolhe a cor

Tags: javascript, html, css

O objetivo principal é que, quando o usuário inserir a cor no campo do formulário, que a cor seja trocada.

Porém, quando o usuário insere a cor, ela é exibida como background e depois volta para a cor original (de início). O erro está quando volta automaticamente para cor de início, mas não sei consertar.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Muda cores</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background: tomato;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .content{
            max-width: 960px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        div input{
            flex: 1;
            font-size: 1em;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        div button{
            flex: 1;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body id="meufundo">  

    <h1>INSIRA A COR DE FUNDO QUE VOCÊ DESEJA</h1>

    <form action=""> 
        <input type="text" id="bgcolor">
        <!-- Ao clicar puxa a função trocarcor() -->
        <input type="submit" value="TROCAR" onclick="trocarcor()"> 
    </form>

    <p id="cor_escolhida"></p>

    <script>
        function trocarcor() {
            //Seleciona o elemento do seletor de cores, pega o seu valor e registra em uma variável.
            let Cor =  document.querySelector('#bgcolor').value;
             //Seleciona o elemento ID em que a cor deve ser trocada, entra no estilho e altera o background para cor inserida e adquirada, através do value anterior.
            document.getElementById('meufundo').style.backgroundColor = Cor;
            //Mostra na tela qual foi a cor escolhida
            document.getElementById('cor_escolhida').innerHTML = `A cor escolhida foi ${Cor}`;
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema é que o seu `input` é type `submit`, e deveria ser type `button`

```
<input type="submit" value="TROCAR" onclick="trocarcor()">
```

Deveria ser

```
<input type="button" value="TROCAR" onclick="trocarcor()">
```

Veja

```js
            function trocarcor() {
                //Seleciona o elemento do seletor de cores, pega o seu valor e registra em uma variável.
                let Cor =  document.querySelector('#bgcolor').value;
                 //Seleciona o elemento ID em que a cor deve ser trocada, entra no estilho e altera o background para cor inserida e adquirada, através do value anterior.
                document.getElementById('meufundo').style.backgroundColor = Cor;
                //Mostra na tela qual foi a cor escolhida
                document.getElementById('cor_escolhida').innerHTML = `A cor escolhida foi ${Cor}`;
            }
```

```css
            body{
                background: tomato;
                color: white;
                font-size: 1.2em;
                font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
            }
            .content{
                max-width: 960px;
                margin: 50px auto;
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
            }

            div input{
                flex: 1;
                font-size: 1em;
                padding: 5px;
            }

            div button{
                flex: 1;
            }
```

```html
    <body id="meufundo">  

        <h1>INSIRA A COR DE FUNDO QUE VOCÊ DESEJA</h1>

        <form action=""> 
            <input type="text" id="bgcolor">
            <!-- Ao clicar puxa a função trocarcor() -->
            <input type="button" value="TROCAR" onclick="trocarcor()"> 
        </form>

        <p id="cor_escolhida"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicionei um **return false;** após o onclick do input

```js
function trocarcor() {
            //Seleciona o elemento do seletor de cores, pega o seu valor e registra em uma variável.
            let Cor =  document.querySelector('#bgcolor').value;
             //Seleciona o elemento ID em que a cor deve ser trocada, entra no estilho e altera o background para cor inserida e adquirada, através do value anterior.
            document.getElementById('meufundo').style.backgroundColor = Cor;
            //Mostra na tela qual foi a cor escolhida
            document.getElementById('cor_escolhida').innerHTML = `A cor escolhida foi ${Cor}`;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Muda cores</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background: tomato;
            color: white;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
        }
        .content{
            max-width: 960px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        div input{
            flex: 1;
            font-size: 1em;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        div button{
            flex: 1;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body id="meufundo">  
    <h1>INSIRA A COR DE FUNDO QUE VOCÊ DESEJA</h1>
    <form action=""> 
        <input type="text" id="bgcolor">
        <!-- Ao clicar puxa a função trocarcor() -->
        <input type="submit" value="TROCAR" onclick="trocarcor();return false;"> 
    </form>
    <p id="cor_escolhida"></p>
</body>
```